# Why do Americans seem to use the word “delicious” less often than I do?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, adjectives, transatlantic-differences

I am a foreigner and now I am in America. I always use the word *delicious* whenever I like food. For example:

> This meat is so delicious!

But one of my friends, who is not a native speaker, once told me that Americans rarely use *delicious*. The more frequent expressions would be “This meat is good” or “This meat is yummy.”

Is *delicious* more of a British English word than an American one?

Comment: I can't speak to relative frequency as compared to British English, but as a native speaker of American English I say and hear 'delicious' to describe food all the time.

Comment: It's a good question, so I can't downvote it -- but it's based on an erroneous assertion, so I keep being tempted to do so.

Comment: Apart from the question of frequency, keep in mind that "yummy" is _VERY_ informal. When in doubt, I'd recommend using "delicious" or "good".

Comment: No, *delicious* is not British English rather than American. If you are using *delicious* every time you merely like the taste of something, then you are watering the term down considerably. It should only be used when you need an absolute superlative.

Comment: It would help to tell what your primary language and culture are, and how you would transliterate the ways you use to say something is good in your own language. I've grown in France and noticed in interacting with Chinese-born visitors in particular that they systematically use the word delicious, and even very delicious, which contrasts sharply with how the French would describe their day-to-day food. When I studied Chinese, I was told that it was common to add "hen" (very) in front of many adjectives.

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding your friend's meaning.  It's not that it's rare, exactly, but you wouldn't call every thing that is good or tasty "delicious," just like you wouldn't call every movie you enjoyed "spectacular."

Comment: I believe this case may be more localised, i.e. it resolves to frequency of usage within town/state rather than simply within countries.

Comment: On re-reading the question, maybe your friends were commenting on your use of the "so" in "so delicious". Just "delicious" will do.

Comment: Maybe Americans are more discerning in their tastes.

Comment: @HotLicks Maybe American food just isn't as good as British. _snigger_

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In my experience as an American:

We do use the word delicious fairly often.  It is not at all unusual or strange.

Its use compared to the more general words "good" and "great" is dependent on context.

For example, if my friend asked me "how's the food?" and I enjoyed the food, I'd more likely use "it's good!" or "it's great!" and reserve "it's delicious!" only for when it's *exceptionally* good.  And this is mostly the case, that "delicious" is simply "more good" or "very good."  A similar word would be "scrumptious."  It's used by many, but it's just less usual because it implies that the food is unusually good.

However, if nobody prompted me, and I simply want to proclaim that the food I'm eating is good, I'd be more tempted to use the word "delicious" because it's specific to food, so it's more easily understood what I'm talking about.

As for "yummy," "tasty," and other such specific words... it's hard to say if they're common.  I rarely hear "yummy" but I hear and say "tasty" quite often.  Definitely more so than "delicious."

Comment: +1 You stated my perspective perfectly.  Delicious is reserved for the most delectable foods.  The word "yummy" has a juvenile or immature connotation for me as a native American English speaker in the Northeast US.

Comment: @Lumberjack As an Englishman, any word ending in -ummy sounds juvenile. (The exception being the type of human that has undergone the mummification process).

Comment: It's really the same here.  The only -ummy word I use is 'tummy' because I find 'abdomen' isn't specific enough and 'stomach' is way too specific when I want to say that my tummy hurts.

Comment: Dummy? Gin Rummy? The gears are all 'gummy'? Let's not get too chummy? (not juvenile, just mostly pretty informal)

Answer (score 11):

I do not often use *delicious* myself, but neither do I consider it unusual or "foreign" in any way.

It may not be that popular in your friend's circles, but the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) has twice as many results for *delicious* as it does for *tasty* and *yummy* combined. The relative numbers are not very different from those in the [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) (though *yummy* is much less common in the latter). It does have an extra syllable, which has probably contributed to the use of *[delish](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delish)*.

There are many ways to approve of the taste of a food or meal; *delicious* is, if anything, so generic and unspecific that it is interchangeable with saying something *tastes good*. So in advertising, food journalism, and the like it is true that *delicious* may be unfavored compared to more colorful words like *[delectable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delectable)* or *[ambrosial](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ambrosial)* or *[scrumptious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scrumptious)* or *[toothsome](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toothsome)*.

As if we Americans needed any more encouragement to eat.

Comment: Regarding the encouragement to eat comment: hehehe.

Comment: On the other hand, occurrences of _anorexia nervosa_ are higher in the US than in non-Western countries.

Comment: We get business from people having medical problems.

Comment: I think you're missing the unsaid point in the OP, and I'm familiar with this because my wife is Korean and kept using "delicious" in conversation when she meant "tasty" (and saying things that sounded strange to my ear, like "this isn't very delicious").  "Delicious" is very strong praise -- "this is delicious" is more akin to "this is fantastic" than "this tastes good."  A lot of foreigners miss this and use it the wrong way.

Comment: There may be a generational aspect to this as well. Children are more likely to say,  'yummy' than adults in my experience - and vice-versa.

Answer (score 5):

If I may submit a couple of Ngrams for comparison.

Corpus: [British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=delicious%2Cyummy%2Ctasty&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdelicious%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyummy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctasty%3B%2Cc0)

Corpus: [American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=delicious%2Cyummy%2Ctasty&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdelicious%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyummy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctasty%3B%2Cc0)

I was not surprised to see that the usage of the word 'delicious' more or less follows the same trend between both <strike>lexicons</strike> corpora. I was a little surprised to see that the term is slightly more popular in American usage than across the pond.

I cannot speak for the usage of any term in Great Britain, but I can say that in my circles, 'delicious' sees frequent usage. Yummy for me is more for when I am trying to convince my 1-yo son to eat his peas.

Comment: Thank you for providing corpus evidence! (Btw, Lexicon isn't the right term for this. A lexicon is essentially a dictionary. Corpus is the appropriate word.)

Comment: Edited. Thanks for the correction! I guess my brain at 1:00 am doesn't exactly fire on cylinders. :/

Answer (score 1):

As someone who works internationally, I can say that, in my experience, speakers of certain other languages use 'delicious' far more than native speakers of the English. It is this relative overuse that becomes jarring. Americans appear more likely to say things like "Damn, that is the best slice of pizza I've ever had" to something involving the word 'delicious'.